# Spark structured streaming - Is it possible to use spark structured streaming window functionality without aggregation?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I am working on a CSV data set and processing using spark streaming. I am able to apply the batch processing using window function in spark streaming. Is there a way I can do the same using spark structured streaming without using the aggregation function? All the examples available on the internet use the groupBy option. I just want to divide the data into batches without any aggregation using structured streaming.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode
from pyspark.sql.functions import split
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

def foreach_batch_function(df, epoch_id):
    #df = df.select(split('value',','))
    #df.show()
    print(type(df))
    df = df.toPandas()
    df = df.value.str.split("," ,expand=True)
    df.show()

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("TurbineDataAnalytics").getOrCreate()

lines = spark.readStream.format("socket").option("host", "localhost").option("port", 8887).load()

lines = lines.groupBy(window(lines.value, "10 minutes", "5 minutes"), lines.value).count()

query = lines.writeStream.foreachBatch(foreach_batch_function).start()

query.awaitTermination()
```

Sample data:

```
Date_Time,Rt_avg,Q_avg,Rs_avg,Rm_avg,Ws_avg,Nu_avg

12/31/16 18:00,12,12.18,9.3500004,742.70001,4.5599999,700.33002

12/31/16 18:10,12,11.35,9.4799995,788.98999,4.9899998,698.03998

12/31/16 18:20,12,11.05,9.2399998,654.10999,4.8400002,700.16998

12/31/16 18:30,12,12,9.5,795.71997,4.6999998,699.37
```

Comment: Please show us your code and your example data. In general it is not required to do an aggregation for structured streaming.

Comment: I have added some part of my code here. Once I have data in batches I wish to send it over to a function in another python file. However, I am not sure how to create batches without aggregation. I am new to spark streaming and any help is appreciated.

Comment: That looks good, but it is still not clear for what kind of output you want to get. Please add a few lines of your input data and some lines of the output you want to get.

Comment: I have added some data from csv. I want to process 1000 records per batch and move the window after every 10 secs for last 30 secs of data. I am able to do this using normal Spark streaming with DStreams. However, I am not sure how to do it with structured streaming.

Comment: I do have a git link to my code. Please let me know if you would be interested in giving it a look.

Comment: So you just want to assign the corrosponding window to each row?

Comment: Yes. I have around 100,000 records in the file. I want to apply window operation without any aggregation.

Comment: Could you please try `lines = lines.select(window(lines.value, "10 minutes", "5 minutes"), lines.value)`?

Comment: I tried this earlier. The problem is lines.value in the window function. The first argument is the timestamp within the data set. However, lines.value contains the entire row within the single column as a continuous string. I am not sure how to split the line before the window function and use Date_Time column in window. My this understanding is from the code mentioned here https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#window-operations-on-event-time

Comment: It really speeds up the process when you mention such things in your question.

Answer (score 0):

According to the things you have mentioned in the comments you want to know how you can split the value column of your dataframe and how you can apply sliding windows without a groupby.

You can split the value column with the [split](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.split) function and apply the sliding windows with a select. Have a look at the pseudocode below:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
#readstream
lines = lines.select(lines.value)

split_col = F.split(df.value, ',')

lines = lines.withColumn('Date_Time', split_col.getItem(0))
lines = lines.withColumn('Rt_avg', split_col.getItem(1))
lines = lines.withColumn('Q_avg', split_col.getItem(2))
lines = lines.withColumn('Rs_avg', split_col.getItem(3))
lines = lines.withColumn('Rm_avg', split_col.getItem(4))
lines = lines.withColumn('Ws_avg',split_col.getItem(5))
lines = lines.withColumn('Nu_avg',split_col.getItem(6))

w = lines.select(F.window("Date_Time", "5 seconds"))
#writeStream
```